# Handling xmlhttpResponse that contain html code, need to modify anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
`var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;

  $(reponseText).$('#products href').each(function(){
                         this.href = "http://www.example.com" + this.href;
                    })
```

`

reponseText contains html code.

Products is a Id of Div element.
I want to pre append all the anchor elements in this div ( products ) like `http://www.example.com/` followed by current href attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only specify the required parts in ajax request page, otherwise xmlhttp.responseText will return all the HTML and print statements given in the request page.

for example, in the case of JSP

```
<html>
<%
out.print("something")
%>
</html>
```

ajax:

`xmlhttp.responseText` will return both html tag and the print text 'something'

actual result will be: `"<html>something</html>"`

so you need to remove unwanted html/printing statements from your request page.